# Solve nonimplication-SAT

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

### Background

This is Post's lattice:

[image: Post's lattice]

<sub>Credit: [EmilJ](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Post-lattice.svg)</sub>

It denotes the lattice of all clones on a two-element set `{0, 1}`, ordered by inclusion (from Wikipedia). That can be a bit of a mouthful so lets look at a concrete example. `MP` (located near the top) is a set that contains all boolean circuits that can be made with `and` and `or`. `DM` (a bit lower) is the set of all boolean circuits that can be made with the majority gate. The majority gate (`maj`) takes three inputs and returns true iff at least two of the inputs are true. This is a hasse diagram ordered by inclusion, which means that since `DM` is below `M` and you can reach it by a sequence of nodes at decreasing heights, `DM` is a (strict) subset of `M`. This means that every circuit that can be made with `maj` can be replicated using `∧` and `∨`.

I've colored the nodes according to the computational complexity of the boolean satisfiability problem restricted to that set of circuits. Green means `O(1)`. This means that either the set is always satisfiable or it contains a finite amount of elements. Yellow is linear time. Red is NP-complete.

As you can see, \$T_0^\infty\$ is the smallest NP-complete set. It is generated by `↛` which is the negation of implication. In other words, it is the set of all formulas consisting of `↛` and brackets.

### Task

Your task is to solve a instance of nonimplication-SAT. That is, you are given a boolean formula consisting of variables and the operator `↛` which has the following truth table:

```
a b a↛b
0 0  0
0 1  0
1 0  1
1 1  0
```

Your program has to decide whether there is an assignment to the variables which satisfies the formula. That is, the value of the formula is `1`.

### Test cases

```
a↛a: UNSAT
a↛b: SAT
(a↛b)↛b: SAT
((a↛(c↛a))↛(b↛(a↛b)))↛(a↛(b↛c)): UNSAT
```

### Rules

This is a decision problem so you should have two distinct output values for SAT and UNSAT. Use a reasonable input format. For example:

```
"(a↛(b↛c))↛(b↛a)"
[[0,[1,2]],[1,0]]
"↛↛a↛bc↛ba"
```

Make sure that the format you choose can handle an unlimited amount of variables. For strings just the letters a to z are not enough as there is only a finite amount of them.

Bonus points if your code runs in polynomial time :p

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
SatisfiableQ[#/.$->(#&&!#2&)]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8YyCxOy0xMykkNjFbW11PRtdNQVlNTVDZS04xV@x9QlJlXEq2soGunkBatHBuroKag76BQrRKdqKOQGKujAGYkgRlwJowLFlCJTgapBAslwdXHwrSCBZOB/Nr/AA)

Takes input in the form `$[$[a, $[b, c]], $[b, a]]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 57 bytes

```
Ｗ⁻⪪⁻⁻θ(¦)¦>υ⊞υ⌊ι⊙…⁰Ｘ²ＬυＵＶ⪫⟦(lambda ⪫λ=0,¦=0:θ)(⪫⮌↨ι²,¦)⟧ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Na8MwDIbv@xXCJwk0CD2u1LDBLqOD0B3LDkpmGoPjdImd0F/vKll3eSS9@njVdjK2g4RSls4HB/jpY57w6xp8euR//GUwaEhJG@3KTAR1njrMDDrm@9yjJ9o/1aOPCV/jDU8SLw4rhnpY3Ig7hqOLl6QrRHqhvqVuiO@zhCzJ4cfgI54NBumbHwHDsClBDQ8Vb8aH6kXl9R3C//7JzW6cHL6JwjPs1tOGH@9@MyxqRvtSEMVia4UsNlbzRuU1atUSlec53AE) Link is to verbose version of code. Accepts any valid Python identifier as a variable name and represents the nonimplication operator with the `>` character. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for satisfiable, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁻⪪⁻⁻θ(¦)¦>υ⊞υ⌊ι
```

Extract all of the unique variable names from the input.

```
⊙…⁰Ｘ²ＬυＵＶ⪫⟦(lambda ⪫λ=0,¦=0:θ)(⪫⮌↨ι²,¦)⟧ω
```

Compute all possible variable substitutions and evaluate the string as python code with those assignments until one evaluates as `True`, at which point output a `-`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 397 bytes:

```py
l=len
b=[{'a':0,'b':0,1:0},{'a':0,'b':1,1:0},{'a':1,'b':0,1:1},{'a':1,'b':1,1:0}]
def g(r):
 if len(r)!=len(b[0])-1:return 0
 if all(str==type(i)for i in r):return all(i in b[0]for i in r)
 return any(all(x==y for x,y in zip(r,[*i.values()][:-1])if type(x)==type(y))for i in b)
def f(d):
 if l(d)!=l(b[0])-1:return 0
 if all(j:=[i if isinstance(i,str)else f(i)for i in d]):
  return g(j)
 return 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBRb4MgFIXf/RXsSe5CF8leFhN@CeFBKnY0hBq0jWzZb3cXqq1m2YPkcu6Xczj2cfy8@PePPsyzE874Qgv5XTZlXbFSp5PX1Q/bKHyj8AfDd8qdUUVrOnKiAeqC2I6gO84vKYVqWSk48DqY8Ro8qTLQOEeHMQgxxt5QC90lEEusJ@iwgAnJUjLY7AuyAj7SBE1CRJKAicWEfNmeBiZf7dutcVczUFCyPnAFmJvjJlhyIzyDNeQOHW3XDjhhg//ff66FtOliB@uHsfFHbMKwFRg3GHTa1GpVcl1ffqLnZ41q7oP1I@2oxN/K8FMAxV7Te@0h/t3klSyPdyOFo073hc9CBlBFCAWA@Rc)